# Accessing ListView Adapter inside ViewPager

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-adapter, searchview

**What I Have**

1) I have an Activity, inside which I have an ActionBar and a fragment.
2) Inside this fragment, I have a ViewPager showing 3-4 fragments.
3) Inside each fragment, there is a different ListView.

**What I Want**

I want to implement ListView filter in ActionBar. That is not a problem, but I cannot access individual adapters of the different lists inside the ViewPager, which is inside a Fragment.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_file_hide_main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    Fragment filesMain = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FILES_MAIN");
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) filesMain.getView().findViewById(R.id.filesViewPager);
    if(viewPager.getAdapter() == null)
        Log.d("TAG", ADAPTER IS NULL");


    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            //adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            //adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);

    return true;
}
```

The adapter is always null and I am also unable to get the adapters of all the ListViews as the user swipes.

Please help with with a solution.

Comment: Don't you have a reference to the view pager adapter from when you set it initially ?

Comment: The ViewPager is inside the Fragment but the onCreateOptionsMenu is inside the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface :

```
public interface ViewPagerPageChangeListener{
    public void updateFragmentPosition(int position);
}
```

MainActivity :

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ViewPagerPageChangeListener(){

  @Override
  public void updateFragmentPosition(int position){
      switch(position){
          case 0 :
          FragmentOne fragmentOne = (FragmentOne)    mainFragment.getActiveFragment(currentPosition);
          break;
          case 1 : 
          FragmentTwo = fragmentTwo = (FragmentTwo) mainFragment.getActiveFragment(currentPosition);
          break;
      }
  }

}
```

Inside the fragment which contains the ViewPager :

```
ViewPagerPageChangeListener listener = (ViewPagerPageChangeListener)getActivity();

mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
            currentPosition = pos;
            listener.updateFragmentPosition(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

public Fragment getActiveFragment(){
    return fragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
}
```

Now, FragmentOne, FragmentTwo etc are the Fragments inside your view pager. Define a method inside these fragment which will update the values in their respective lists.

Now, whenever the current item changes inside the view pager, your main activity gets a notification. You can then grab the fragment from the viewpager and update the currently visible fragment and cast it to the relevant fragment class.

Now when you do the search, just call `fragmentOne.updateList(String filterText); or fragmentTwo.updateList(String filterText);`